# Enable HTTP context in WCF service

Tags: wcf

i added

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

but it's giving me an error"

```
The service cannot be activated because it requires ASP.NET compatibility. ASP.NET compatibility is not enabled for this application
```

it seems like the WCF service has no HTTP context related to it? please help

Comment: Have you added the AspNetCompatibility attribute on your service contract?

Answer (score -1):

It has check out the following link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx

and make sure you have added this tag in your web config

Comment: Some more detail in this answer would be good, rather than just a link.